# Rails modules - Including diffrent module during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, module

So i have that problem:

I have my class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initalize :include_proper_module

  private
  def include_proper_module
    if variable1 = 1
      self.class.send(:include, Module1)
    else
      self.class.send(:include, Module2)
    end
  end
end
```

and it works fine, until i ran all tests - then if the one of tests include Module1 then its always included.

I use database_cleaner with deletion strategy, and dont have any idea where or how should i debug it. Is there any option to reset all included modules after/before test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is wrong, regardless the test. In fact, the inclusion of the module affects the entire class definition.

It does not make sense to conditionally include a module depending on an instance variable. As soon as the variable is 1, the `Module1` is mixed into the class for **every user** instance. And as soon as the variable is different than 1, the `Module2` will be mixed into the user class for **every user**.

The result is that every user instance will quickly include both modules.

I believe this is what the test is revealing. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but that's not the right way.

Comment: Oh i see, didnt thought about that , that when i include module for class it affeccts already existings object of that class - and its quite obvious. Thanks!